# How to disable shadow on text?

Tags: css, text, shadow

what code should I remove/ add to so that the text isn't hard to read on this URL: [Marketbot.net](http://marketbot.net)

I want plain black text, not a popup shadowed text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `#slider-bg` styling inside your `flexslider.css` file.

Here is what's defined for it currently:

[image]

Just remove the `text-shadow` and change the color to black.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the text-shadow from the style of your `body{}` inside your `css` in the file `style.css` line:63 :)